# На странице справки о конкурсах ссылка на общие вопросы ведёт на MSE

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki